# How to find the dual function when the objective function and constraints are linear?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

[image]
When I try to compute the dual function by taking the derivative of the Lagrangian I just find the values of $\lambda_{1} = \frac{2}{3} $ and $\lambda_{2} = \frac{1}{3}$. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The dual function $g(\lambda)$ is the minimum value of the Lagrangian for a fixed $\lambda$.  You should be optimizing with respect to $x$ for a fixed $\lambda$.

Comment: That is what I did, but when I take the derivative with respect to either $x_{1}$ or $x_{2}$. The values do not depend on  $x_{1}$ or $x_{2}$ anymore. Namely, with respect to $x_{1}$ , I get $-1 + \lambda_{1} +  \lambda_{2}$ and with respect to $x_{2}$ I get $\lambda_{1} - 2\lambda_{2}$ then solving for $\lambda$ this yields the values above.

Comment: @Max Add all the details of what you have tried so far and we'll help you out.